# SQLALCHEMY query filter id <

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, queryselector

```
todos = Todo.query.filter_by(id>int(request.form.get("id"))).all()
```

This gives the error.

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

I know my mistake But I don't know how I can do this. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Query.filter`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) instead of [`Query.filter_by`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by):

```
todos = Todo.query.filter(Todo.id>int(request.form.get("id"))).all()
```

Answer (score -1):

okey
i do it:

```
    id = int(request.form.get("id"))
while True:
    if ....:
        code
        return ....
    else:
         id += 1
```

Comment: That is probably not a idea, since you do way more queries than necessary, potentially overloading your memory or your database